# Apache Camel CXF endpoint null reply

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I followed chapter 7 of Camel in Action book and implemented a CXF route.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint 
    id="orderEndpoint" 
    address="http://localhost:9000/order/"
    serviceClass="test.order.OrderEndpoint" 
    wsdlURL="wsdl/order.wsdl" />


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <!-- Expose route as web service endpoint -->
        <from uri="cxf:bean:orderEndpoint" />
        <to uri="log:orderEndpoint_MsgIn" />
        <to uri="seda:incomingOrders" />
        <transform>
            <constant>OK</constant>
        </transform>
        <to uri="log:orderEndpoint_MsgOut" />
    </route>

    <!-- test route -->
    <route>
        <from uri="seda:incomingOrders" />
        <to uri="mock:end" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Then I implemented a java console class to test the route

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Main main = new Main(); 
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "META-INF/spring/cxfWsComponentTestContext.xml"
            );

    main.setApplicationContext(context);

    main.start();
    ProducerTemplate producer = main.getCamelTemplate();

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    params.add("motor");
    params.add(1);
    params.add("honda");

    String reply = producer.requestBody("cxf:bean:orderEndpoint", params, String.class);
    LOG.info("Received reply from orderEndpoint = " + reply);

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    main.stop();

}
```

Expect that the console log should display

```
"Received reply from orderEndpoint = OK"
```

However, I got

```
"Received reply from orderEndpoint = null"
```

In the console log I can see that the entry

```
"orderEndpoint_MsgOut           INFO  Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: OK]"
```

which means that the Web service should have generated reply message "OK", but I'm not sure why this reply message was not carry over as a return value of the requestBody() method call...

I downloaded Camel in Action chapter 7's sample code and run the Junit test case, it was able to return the result as expected... I tried to compare the route definitions and source code with mine but not able to spot any difference so far...

Would like to see if anyone can give some clues on this.

--- Edit 1 ---

I have updated the route definition and remain only the route as below

```
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:orderEndpoint" />
        <transform>
            <constant>OK</constant>
        </transform>
        <to uri="seda:incomingOrders" />
    </route>
```

And updated the main method

```
    producer.requestBody("cxf:bean:orderEndpoint", params, String.class);
    ConsumerTemplate consumer = producer.getCamelContext().createConsumerTemplate();
    Exchange reply = consumer.receive("seda:incomingOrders");
    LOG.info("Received reply from seda:incomingOrders = " + reply);
```

However, it failed with timeout exception

```
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 30000 millis. Exchange[Message: OK]
at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer.process(SedaProducer.java:144)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting the body of the CXF endpoint. If you look at your route, you can see that you set the content of the body in the transform tag, which comes after in the route definition. Therefore, it is logical that you don't get OK as a result of `requestBody()`. The same applies to your seda endpoint. I'd bet that the Logged body for `orderEndpoint_MsgIn` is different from OK.

Concerning your log at `orderEndpoint_MsgOut` being correct, it is because you log the body after the transform step.

In order to receive OK, you can use this route :

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:orderEndpoint" />
    <transform>
        <constant>OK</constant>
    </transform>
    <wireTap uri="seda:incomingOrders" />
</route>
```

And use `ConsumerTemplate` with the seda endpoint :

```
ConsumerTemplate consumer = producer.getCamelContext().createConsumerTemplate();
String reply = consumer.receive("seda:incomingOrders");
LOG.info("Received reply from seda = " + reply);
```

You should use this code between the `requestBody()` and the `main.stop()`.

For an explanation on the use of `wireTap` rather than `to`, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626541/org-apache-camel-exchangetimedoutexception-the-out-message-was-not-received-wit)

Comment: You are correct that the orderEndpoint_MsgIn is different from "OK" -- it logged the cxf MessageContestsList object with body equals to one of the incoming parameter "motor", like below:  

    orderEndpoint_MsgIn            INFO  Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, Body: motor]
 
Could you please advice how should I modify the route or the Main program in order to get the "OK" reply string?

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working... I have edited my original question with latest exception found

Comment: @xlogger You can see in the stack trace that the exchange body is OK. It seems that your problem is the same than here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626541/org-apache-camel-exchangetimedoutexception-the-out-message-was-not-received-wit , I edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your updates and reference link. I got it worked now. My only comment is that your code on ConsumerTemplate did not work as there is no createConsumerTemplate() method in main (I test with Camel 2.15.0). I got it work by getting the consumer template from Camel context instead (see my edited code)... wish you could make a final edit on the consumer template code before I mark your answer as accepted answer. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @xlogger it should be consistent with your snippet now.